# I cant use alertdialog builder in android activity and has runtime error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

when the app wants to use this and click the button the run time error occurs and I dont know how to fic this , and this code used in fragment and now I nedd to use this in activity and I think its the problem

```
post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this);

            CharSequence items[] = {"گرفتن تصویر از دوربین","گرفتن ویدیو از دوربین",
                    "انتخاب تصویر از گالری","انتخاب ویدیو از گالری"};
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewPost.this);
            ab.setTitle("انتخاب از :");
            ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    switch (position)
                    {
                        case 0 :
                            take_pic_from_camera();
                            break;
                        case 1 :
                            take_video_from_camera();
                            break;
                        case 2 :
                            pick_pic_from_gallery();
                            break;
                        case 3 :
                            pick_video_from_gallery();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            ab.create().show();
        }
    });
```

and my error is :
09-18 07:33:07.618 8846-8846/com.irprogram.ted E/AndroidRuntime:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.irprogram.ted, PID: 8846
                                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:880)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:857)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:899)
                                                                     at com.irprogram.ted.NewPost$2.onClick(NewPost.java:165)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Post your error log too.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this code snippet...`ResourceNotFoundException on getValue() line 190 of ResourcesImpl class`

Answer (score 0):

You called `setItems` method before showing it. Just try to make a change in your code so that you call `ab.create().show();` before `ab.setItems()`.

The exception may be because it can't set the `OnClickListeneter` before making it visible in the activity.

Hope it helps.